# Wrapping JQuery function results with <p> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

Hi I have an interactive graphing function. Because of some limitations, I have to delete the figure every time the user interacts with the graphic using:

```
$("button").click(function () {
     $("p").empty();
 });
```

However, then I want to regenerate the graphic by calling (in protovis):

```
drawHistogram(){
var w = 420
var h = 300
var vis = new pv.Panel()
.width(w)
.height(h)
.margin(20);
//add data into the visualization
vis.render();
}
```

in JQuery. However, now this graphic isn't surrounded by the `<p>` tags so when I click the button, nothing will happen in this iteration. How would I surround the `drawHistogram()` call with `<p>` tags? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code for `drawHistogram()`?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little hard to decide the best way to do this without seeing how drawHistogram() works.

Comment: How does the graphic get into the `<p>` tags in the first place, before you `$.empty()` them?

Comment: Your title says `<div>` but your question says `<p>`. Which is it? And you can't wrap _jQuery functions_ with html.

Answer (score 0):

If `drawHistogram()` is a PHP function:

```
<?php
    function drawHistogram() {
?>

    <P>

<?php

    // Draw Histogram code goes here

?>

    </p>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element the vis.render(); renders just access it and wrap it using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
<div class="vis-rendered">
  <div class="inner">Vis Image</div>
</div>

$('.vis-rendered').wrap('<p />');
```

Result:

```
<p>
  <div class="vis-rendered">
    <div class="inner">Vis Image</div>
  </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery .wrap() to wrap the element inside a `<p>` element.

if the unwrapped .inner element looked like this to start:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Then you use `$('.class').wrap('<p>')` on the rendered element:

```
$('.inner').wrap('<p class="new" />');
```

The wrapped results would look like:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </p>
  <p class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a container element and every time you call `drawHistogram()`, inside that method you wrap the result within a `"<p>"` element.

Here, see if this example will help.

http://jsfiddle.net/BP5hb/

Best,